# If $A^2 = I$, then $\operatorname{rank} (A+I) + \operatorname{rank} (A-I) =n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

If $A^2 = I$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then why is $\operatorname{rank} (A+I) + \operatorname{rank} (A-I) =n$.

I am not sure why this seems to be true.